# where is the “Enable Offline Cache Mode” in Chrome 38?

Tags: google-chrome

Looking for a way to work offline (when in the train...), reading my already open Chrome tabs. Too often do I loose the content of these tabs because of Chrome trying to refresh it... which inevitably ends up with a no network error page.

Found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/459196/is-it-possible-to-work-offline-in-google-chrome-as-in-firefox/660791#660791) superuser similar question and [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/) Chrome team developer blog post. Both mention looking in chrome://flags for the “Enable Offline Cache Mode” property and switch it to "enabled". Trouble is that may have been true for Chrome 35 (mentioned in blog post), but property no longer exists in 38.

Similar looking properties are:
- Enable Offline Auto-Reload Mode
- Enable Offline Load Stale Button
- Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs

Is one of these the new "Enable Offline Cache Mode”?

Comment: Welcome to SU!  This is the same question you linked.  If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please consider earning some [rep](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) and placing [a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) (and some comments) on the original instead of asking the same thing again.

Comment: Problem is getting the initial rep... Easiest way being... asking a question.

Comment: Check this recent Meta question out: [How to build up Comment privileges?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8634/how-to-build-up-comment-privileges)

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from your second link (http://addyosmani.com/blog/offline-mode-chrome/) was that the feature of automatically loading a cached copy has been replaced by the `Enable Show Saved Copy Button` option (where you initially get the "Unable to connect" page but with an additional "Show saved copy" button for manually loading the cached copy).
Just confirmed it on Google Chrome 43.0.2357.65 beta.

Comment: @user5359531 - Of course it does not work with Chrome 49, this was asked, before Chrome 49 was released.  So there isn't a reason to say, it doesn't work with Chrome 49, because it was only confirmed to be work with Chrome 43 beta.  If you don't have reputation to comment, you don't comment until you do, making invalid edits will just end up with you losing that privilege.